# sql simple question help

Tags: sql

I need to return all of the names of people that contain certain letters, or a combination of letters.

for example

```
names = bob, mary, nick
```

return names with the letter "b"

```
returns bob
```

return names with the letter "ar"

```
returns mary
```

so

```
SELECT name
FROM people
WHERE ???
```

Comment: Are those names in a single column, e.g. comma-separated inside a column?? That would be a really really bad design for a SQL database....

Comment: no, the values are atomic each name has it's own space with-in the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE name LIKE '%ar%'
```

for MS-Access, use

```
WHERE name LIKE '* ar *'
```

Ignore the spaces between * and 'ar'. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/like-operator-HP001032253.aspx

Comment: hmmm. its not working with the datebase we were given in microsoft access the table name all have "-" in them so the names have to be placed within square brackets, could that be a problem

Comment: we all assume that you've a table called "people", with a column called "name", is that correct? If so, the samples we presented you should work. Can you give some more details, like database type, and which tool you use to try this query.

Comment: its just the sql editor in access. i went SELECT [people-name] FROM people, which works, but when i say WHERE [people-name] LIKE '%ar%'; it dosn't work

Comment: MS-Access uses different wildcards than other SQL based solutions. I edited my original post, have a look

Comment: no, SELECT [people-name] FROM people WHERE [people-name] LIKE "mary"; will return mary. but if i change it to "ar" it won't work, beside i think the % are accepted

Comment: fixed it the % needs to be a *. Thank-you, i thought access accepted %, oh well :)

Comment: I edited my post again just after you read it, I placed asterisks around the 'ar', but in StackOverflow this means the text will be printed italic style. Now, see the post and try to 'wrap' your search string in asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name 
FROM people 
WHERE name like '%ar%'
```

`%` is like "what ever"
you can use `LIKE` and `%` just for string fields

Answer (score 0):

Use 'like' operator by using that you can do it

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE NAME LIKE '%<letter-or-string>%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name 
FROM people 
WHERE name like '%ar%'  ----returns Mary

WHERE name like 'b%'    ----returns bob

WHERE name like  '%k'   ----returns nick
```

Note: Do not execute all the 'where' conditions together.